# Apache Camel: How do I signal to other processes that I moved/renamed a file?

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to develop a file receipt process using Camel. what I am trying to do seems simple enough:

- receive a file
- invoke a web service which will look at that file and generate some metadata
- move the file to a new location based on that metadata
- invoke subsequent process(es) which will act on the file in it's new location

I have tried several different approaches but none seem to work exactly as I would like. My main issues are that since the file is not moved/renamed until the route is completed, I cannot signal to any downstream process that the file is available within that route.

I need to invoke webservices in order to determine the new name and location, once I do that the body is changed and I cannot use a file producer to move the file from within the route.

I would really appreciate hearing any other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can signal the processing routes and then have them poll using the doneFile functionality of the file component.

Your first process will copy the files, signal the processing routes, and when it is done copying the file it will write a done file.  Once the done file has been written the file consumers in your processing routes will pick up the file you want to process.  This guarantees that the file is written before it is processed.

Check out the "Using done files" section of the file component.

http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Comment: I had forgotten about the done file. Poling wasn't working out for me because I wouldn't necessarily know the exact file name and other processes might create files in the same directory. But, using doneFile I would have control of the file name and poll for just that.

I have actually since resolved it by having the process that was called copy the file and allowing the route to delete it. I think though this solution may have worked as well.

Thank you both for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Using other components you could have used the OnCompletion DSL-syntax to trigger a post-route message for futher processing.

However, with the file component, this is not really doable, since the move/done thingy happends in parallell with that "OnCompletion" trigger, and you can't be sure that the file is really done.

You might have some luck with the [Unit of Work API](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spi/UnitOfWork.html) which can register post route execution logic (this is how the File component fires of the move when the route is done).

However, do you really need this logic?
I see that you might want to send a wakeup call to some file consumer, but do the file really have to be ready that very millisec?  Can't you just start to poll for the file and grab it once ready, once you received the trigger message? That's ususually how you do things with file based protocols (or just ignore the trigger and poll once every now and then).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't really need subsequent process to be triggered that quickly (to get around the issues I am facing I have put a 10 second delay in the subsequent route).

I was reading more documentation and it looked as though the Routing Slip pattern might work? With the first endpoint being the webservice to gather metadata that determines the final location and  the second being the copying of the file?